# How to make gitconfig's InsteadOf work with Cargo?

Tags: git, rust, rust-cargo

I have the following in my ~/.gitconfig:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
       pushInsteadOf = https://github.com/
       insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Unfortunately today I discovered that this prevents me from making `cargo build` download dependencies for me:

```
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to get `libc` as a dependency of package `hilbert-c2rust v0.1.4 (/home/d33tah/workspace/profound/hilbert-c2rust)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `libc`

Caused by:
  Unable to update registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  failed to authenticate when downloading repository
attempted ssh-agent authentication, but none of the usernames `git` succeeded

Caused by:
  no authentication available
```

Is there a workaround for this problem? Commenting out the lines temporarily helps, but I'd like to keep them because they solve a problem related to Github for me.

Comment: "Caused by: no authentication available" Do you have an ssh-agent running with a key unlocked?

Comment: @mcarton: Actually I do

Comment: Do you have a `.git/config` in your project?

Answer (score 24):

Set env var CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI to true.

Comment: export CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true

Comment: this did it for me, installing cargo on an M1 Mac with git SSH creds set up :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this (from [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8172#issuecomment-659066173)):

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com

[url "https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason creating an `ssh-agent` and adding your identities to the agent did it for me.

```sh
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
cargo build
```

I believe this fix is particular to cargo because you can still pull and push to private repositories and yet the authentication will fail on cargo update.

Answer (score 0):

This also occurs when the user's git is configured with ssh and cargo is unable to find the key configured.

To solve this navigate to '.ssh' file and run `ssh-add id_rsa` and then try again.

This is the only solution that worked for me after hours of head hunting.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ~/.cargo
touch config
```

edit `config` with whatever you want i.e `nvim config` and paste this

```
[net]
git-fetch-with-cli = true
```

- [Source](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3381#issuecomment-710388554)